# How to write decider function for multiple models

Tags: scikit-learn, image-classification, text-classification, ensemble

I have trained two classifiers .. Text Classification and Image Classification.
So both models gives score for each class. For example there are 3 classes. Each model give array of 3 confidence score for each class.

I want to write some decider function to predict the final class based on these two model results.
Dataset is very less around 100 observations.

What possible solution i can try.

Comment: the two scores can be seen as new data and use any classification or regression scheme to derive the final outcome

Comment: i have tried that but the dataset is very less the Linear and Logistic regression doesnt seem to work...